mongoose aggregation for show inline array foreign key s field such as name
my basic table schema :
in this document for each federation has some fields
const basic_federationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, require: true },
    field: [{
        name: { type: String },
    }],
   
}, { strict: false });

basic_federationSchema.plugin(timestamp);

const Basic_federation = mongoose.model("Basic_federation", basic_federationSchema);
module.exports = Basic_federation;


and my main document use some field
const tournamentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    tournamentName: { type: String },
    tournamentFields: [{
        fieldId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Basic_federation.field" },
    },],

}, { strict: false });
// WHEN USE { strict: false } YOU CAN ADD FIELD IN UPDATE COMMAND
tournamentSchema.plugin(timestamp);

const Tournament = mongoose.model("Tournament", tournamentSchema);
module.exports = Tournament;


i want show name of fields in resul
how to get output this result :
{
  tournamentName : "a",
  tournamentFields:[
     {fieldId:1 , name:"field1name"},
    {fieldId:2 , name:"field1name"},  
]


}

thanks
mongoose aggregation for show inline array foreign key s field such as name
